# Codeigniter - cannot load any view at all

Tags: codeigniter, continuous-integration

I have built a website with the CodeIgniter framework.

Unfortunately, I am having a problem with CodeIgniter's `load->view()` function.

Every time I try to load another view file with the code `$this->load->view('any_view_file');` I get the error:

> unable to load the requested file 'any_view_file'.php

For example i am having problems with the *$this->load->view('available_lessons.php', $data);* command. So let's try to recreate the problem and think this through...

1. I am calling the *load_available_lessons()* function of the *Lessons.php* controller
2. The *load_available_lessons()* function uses the *get_lessons()* function of the *db_model.php* model and saves the result on the *$data['result']*.
3. Then, the *load_available_lessons()* function calls the *available_lessons* view file while parsing the *$data* to it.
4. Here is where the problem rises. CodeIgniter is unable to load the view. As i explained earlier, CodeIgniter fails to load any view...!!!

Any suggestions please?

**My .htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|images|css|lessons|robotos\\.txt)  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**From my config.php file:**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**From my routes.php file:**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

**My Pages.php Controller:**

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

        public function view($page = 'home')
        {
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
                {
                        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                        show_404();
                }
                else
                {
                $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
                }
        }
}
?>
```

**My Lessons.php Controller:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Lessons extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('db_model');
                /* $this->load->library('acl'); */
                /* $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url')); */
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->view('available_lessons', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }

        public function load_available_lessons()
        {
            $data['result'] = $this->db_model->get_lessons();
            $this->load->view('available_lessons.php', $data); /* available_lessons */
        }
}
?>
```

**My db_model.php Model:**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class db_model extends CI_Model{

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
        }


        public function new_lesson($data)
        {
            /* Inserting in Table "lessons" of CodeIgniter's Database */
            $this->db->insert('available_lessons', $data);
        }

        public function get_lessons() /* $data */
        {
            /* Get lessons from Table "lessons" of CodeIgniter's Database */
            $this->db->select('Name, Description, DateAdded, LastEdit, UserID, FileName');
            $this->db->from('lessons');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $result = $query->result();
        }
}

?>
```

**My available_lessons.php View file:**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>

<div class="container">
  <h6 class="description">Browse Lessons</h6>
  <div class="row">
    <section id="lessons-panel" class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Content</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($this->result  as $r): ?>
        <tr><?php echo $r->content; ?>

            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your `any_view_file.php` in a subdirectory under /views you need to do `$this->load->view('subdir/any_view_file.php', '');`

Comment: @ourmandave if view is a php file you don't need to include `.php` http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-a-view $this->load->view('subdir/any_view_file');

Comment: Did you name your filenames correct for controllers http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @ourmandave No, it is not in a subdirectory. It is just inside the view folder.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Yes, i think i have named them correctly.
Thank you all for your answers!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: some of my views: "contact.php", "lesson_upload.php", "home.php", "register.php",...
some of my controllers: "Account.php", "Pages.php", "Upload.php", "Dropzone.php",...

Comment: If your config setting $config['index_page'] = ''; is a direct copy, you are missing a ". You need 2 ""

Comment: @Brad it is ' ' ; not ' ;
In other words i have: equal, single apostrophe, single apostrophe **again** and then question mark. Is this correct? I think it has been this way all along...

Comment: I have updated the original question with more information. Any suggestions please? I am going crazy over here... :(

Comment: As a coworker pointed out to me, i should add the "pages/" before every view name that i want to call.
For example, in the Lessons.php controller, i should have $this->load->view('pages/available_lessons.php', $data);
As i turned out he is right. The thing is that i cannot understand the reason why i should include the "pages/". I have already included this in the Pages.php controller...

Comment: So, @ourmandave was right from the very start!!! This is what happens when you are exhausted....
Thank you all for your valuable input!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As @ourmandave and a coworker pointed out to me, i should add the "pages/" before every view name that i want to call. For example, in the Lessons.php controller, i should have $this->load->view('pages/available_lessons.php', $data); As it turned out he is right.
The thing is that i cannot understand the reason why i should include the "pages/" as I have already included this in the Pages.php controller. It seems that the Pages Controller is not being used when i call a view. I will have to look into it later on.
Thank you all for your valuable input!!!!! Just another rookie mistake...